# Fail to install rpy2 from pycharm

Tags: pip, pycharm, rpy2

To install rpy2 in PyCharm I try with `pip install rpy2`. However, it returns a syntax error.

When I did this from my Mac, the same happened, but then I went to settings > project interpreter and installed rpy2 from there without problems. However, now that I am working with Windows, I get the following error:

> pycparser.plyparser.ParseError: :23:5: before:
>   blah1

Any ideas on what might be going on and what can I do?

Thanks!

Comment: I am having this same problem, was this resolved?

Comment: @TanMath In the end I choose rpy2 as a Project Interpreter in Settings, and this was the only way to go forward. However, it feels like there should be another way to do it, but this made it for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I went to Settings and selected rpy2 as a Project Interpreter. It feels like there should be another, simpler, way to do it. But that is what made it for me.